# Mvc 3 redirecting routes behaving weirdly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days now with no success.
 The case is i have rewritten an old web forms site to mvc 3 and have a bunch of legacy url:s that need to be redirected to new url:s

This is what the 2 routes look like in global.asax that should catch all requests to old url:s

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "legacyevents",
            "events/{*slug}",
            new { controller = "Redirect", action = "RedirectLegacyRoute" },
            new[] { "Web.Controllers" }
          );

            routes.MapRoute(
            "legacyarticles",
            "articles/{*slug}",
            new { controller = "Redirect", action = "RedirectLegacyRoute" },
            new[] { "Web.Controllers" }
          );
```

The weird thing is now that when a request looks like this

```
events/randomevent__12.aspx
```

everything works well but if the E in events is upper case  Events/randomevent__12.aspx
asp.net somewhere adds another events word to the url so it looks like this when it hits the RedirectController

```
events/events/randomevent__12.aspx
```

Due to lack of knowledge about SEO when i wrote the web forms app few years back alot of incoming links to the old urls have mixed casing :( so i really have to fix this issue

The route that should handle articles works as intended and does not care about the casing of the incoming request url which which makes this case so weird, since the routes are pointed to the same RedirectController.

Any help will be appreciated and if you need any additional info i will happily provide it

best regards

//K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do know that you can use full power of regular expressions in your route matching?

See examples [here](http://iridescence.no/post/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx).